# WHILE DO READ cannot open file directed in, even though it exists?

Tags: bash, docker, shell

Running into a weird issue while running a docker container (Ubuntu). I copy in some scripts, those scripts should run read a file line by line and execute a command.

When I type out the commands in the shell, it works as I expect. When I have the exact commands in a .sh file, it fails. I've tried every iteration of While read, IFS, changing file permissions, checking spaces, delimiters, etc. Cant seem to make it work.

I'm sure is something simple, but I have yet to find it.

My script:

```
while read LINE;
    do echo "$LINE";
done < "/megacmd/syncs"
```

Contents of `syncs` file:

```
$ cat syncs
sourcedir1 destdir1
sourcedir2 destdir2
sourcedir3 destdir3
```

Output when running the script:

```
# pwd
/megacmd
# ls
exclude.sh  excludes  init.sh  sync.sh  sync2.sh  sync3.sh  sync4.sh  syncs
# ./sync.sh
: No such filecannot open /megacmd/syncs
#
```

Why is there no space between filecannot?

Finally, when I'm manually writing this, it works fine:

```
# while read LINE;
> do echo "$LINE";
> done < "/megacmd/syncs"
sourcedir1 destdir1
sourcedir2 destdir2
sourcedir3 destdir3
#
```

edit1:

```
# ./sync.sh
: No such filecannot open /megacmd/syncs
# file syncs
syncs: ASCII text
#
```

Comment: `: No such file` Your script has dos line endings. Remove them.

Comment: It's trying to open `/megacmd/syncs\r`, not `/megacmd/syncs`.

Comment: I tried recreating the file as a non DOS file, and still get the same result


@chepner I tried removing any extraneous lines at the end of the script with no change.

Comment: `sync.sh` and `syncs` are not the same file. It's `sync.sh` that needs to have its DOS line endings converted to Unix line endings.

Comment: Thank you @chepner ! you were correct. the .sh file was not correct.

Answer (score 1):

[@chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841) was [correct](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/126598725).

My script file was not saved with the correct line ending.
A quick change in Notepad++ fixed it

Comment: [Character encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) is different from line endings. I suggest you correct your answer to say "not saved with the right line endings".